# How do I check if two arrays are the same or different

Tags: c++

I need to check to see if both my arrays are the same or different. 
testScores is two dimensional and answerKey is one dimensional.

I've tried to do this:

```
if (testScores[student][20] != answerKey[0]){
  cout<<"Right
  cout<<endl;
} else {
  cout<<"Not working";
  cout<<endl;
}
```

but still doesn't work

```
if (testScores == answerKey){
  sum +=1;
  cout<<"Sum: "<<sum;
} else if (testScores != answerKey) {
  sum -= 1;
  cout<<"Sum: "<<sum;
} else(testScores = ' ')
  sum += 0;
cout<<"Sum: "<<sum;
}
```

Comment: To compare an array you need a loop.

Comment: Can you give more context? Is testScores an array of string? What is the desired output and what are you getting with this code?

Comment: hard to tell what you're going for here. is `testScores[student]` an array of answers the same length as `answerKey` ? What are the types of `testScores` and `answerKey`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details I provided. Both arrays are of type char. So basically, I need to read through testScores and check to see if it is the same as the answerKey array. answerKey array has 20 characters. For each character that testScores shares with answerKey, 2 is added to sum, if there's a difference, 1 is deducted from sum. I'm not sure which loop to use or if this code should be in a function or can be done in the main.

Comment: See my answer.  Adjust it to type `char` instead of `int`.

Comment: Your other requirements of adding or subtracting a sum is not related to the title of the topic.  The way StackOverflow works is to ask one question at a time per thread.  The answer to "how to compare if two arrays are same or different" is done by the answer given (people are doing searches for how to do this, and don't want to see an answer that is different than what was asked).  Please open another question if the requirements are different.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I check if two arrays are the same or different

You can use [std::equal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal).  That's the purpose of that function, to test if two ranges (in your case, arrays) are the same or different.

Here is an example using just one student, but two answer keys with only 5 answers each.  Please expand this to accommodate the actual number of students and answers.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   const int numStudents = 1;
   const int numScores = 5;
   int testScores[numStudents][numScores] = {{10,20,30,40,50}};
   int answerKey[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
   int answerKey2[] = {10,20,30,40,60};

   for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; ++i)
   {
      if (std::equal(&testScores[i][0], 
                     &testScores[i][numScores + 1], answerKey))
         std::cout << "Student has all right answers for key 1\n";
      else
         std::cout << "Student does not have all right answers for key 1\n";
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; ++i)
   {
      if (std::equal(&testScores[i][0], 
                     &testScores[i][numScores + 1], answerKey2))
         std::cout << "Student has all right answers for key 2\n";
      else
         std::cout << "Student does not have all right answers for key 2\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Student has all right answers for key 1
Student does not have all right answers for key 2
```

Comment: I'm reading data from a file so can I use a similar code structure like this?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the data comes from.  If you populate the arrays with the data, then this will work.  I populated the arrays by hand for demonstration purposes.  However, the whole point of this answer is that you use `std::equal` -- that's the key.